# Chrome does not accept self signed certificate but accepts dotnet developers certificate

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel

I am trying to add self signed certificate to ASP.NET Core MVC website but chrome browser is not accepting it. Showing message Certificate is not valid.

The self signed certificate is created with powershell as given on the below 2 links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

The appsettings.json file is:

```
{
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "MyHttpEndpoint": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "MyHttpsEndpoint": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "SslProtocols": [ "Tls12", "Tls13" ],
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "mypfx.pfx",
          "Password": "1234"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error on the browser:
[image]

But when I use dot net developers certificate then chrome accepts is. Here in this case the appsettings.json is:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "MyHttpEndpoint": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "MyHttpsEndpoint": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See image in this case:

[image]

Why this things comes?

Comment: First time you started debugging with dev certificates, you probably got a certificate installation popup asking you to "trust this certificate". When you clicked OK the dev certificates were [installed as trusted roots in your certificate store](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-essentials-and/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in/ba-p/396105), which is why your browser now trusts it. Do the same for your self-generated cert and it'll work the same

Comment: The dev certificate itself is self-signed. Why are you trying to add *another* self-signed certificate? If you want your web app to be trusted by all browsers you'll have to use a valid certificate, like those issued by Lets Encrypt. In an Active Directory domain, computers also trust certificates issued by the domain's Certificate Services

Comment: You can check `csrtlm.msc` and browse around